# SelectSingleNode returns error has an invalid token

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to get the value of the Token node and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

This is for a vb.net application to send an XML string to a URL

this is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
-<soap:Body>
-<ProcessRequestResponse xmlns="http://itiwnet.com/WebServices/">
-<ProcessRequestResult>
-<fiAPI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://integration.fiapi.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://integration.fiapi.com/fiAPI.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlenc#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ITI="http://www.ITIWnet.com/">
+<fiHeader Version="2.2">
-<Response TypeOfResponse="LoginRs" ResponseID="ReqID" More="false">
+<Status>
<Token>some really long stringToken>
</Response>
</fiAPI>
</ProcessRequestResult>
</ProcessRequestResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
     Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
     nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
     nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
     nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
     nsmgr.AddNamespace("xenc", "http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlenc#")
     nsmgr.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmlsig#")
     nsmgr.AddNamespace("ITI", "http://www.ITIWnet.com")
     txtToken.Text = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode               ("soap:Body\ProcessRequestResponse\ProcessRequestResult\fiAPI\Response\Token"     , nsmgr).InnerText
```

I'm trying to get the value of the Token node
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The invalid token is a backslash. XPath only uses forward slashes.

Comment: Ah..I did not know that. I replaced the back slashes with forward slashes but now I get the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  on the same line. Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't figure out the Name Space issue so I just stripped out all of the namesspaces. Probably not the "best" solution but it works for now. Any other ideas would be quite helpful.

Comment: If you have supplementary questions please raise them as new questions, not as comments on an answer. And describe them with as much care as you described the original problem.